# Installing Office2010

Tags: software-installation, wine

wine cmd.exe /c echo '%ProgramFiles%' returned empty string, error message 'wine: WINEARCH set to win32 but '/home/ramya/.wineprefixes/office2010' is a 64-bit installation.'

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend `PlayOnLinux` if you're going to use Microsoft Office 2010 with Ubuntu.

Install `PlayOnLinux`:

```
sudo apt install playonlinux
```

After `PlayOnLinux` is installed, run the application.  Click on the Install button.

[image]

Then in the search box you can type in `Office 2010` and it will show you the installations.  Click on the correct one, then click Install in the lower right corner of the window.  `PlayOnLinux` should then download all required packages to try to make Microsoft Office 2010 work with Ubuntu.

[image]

Hope this helps!